# install already built Linux environment

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, cloning

I have configured aMint-based environment : openVpn, hostapd, and a bunch of other configured package. This is done on a rasp-like computer (OEM).

I planned to **clone** my disk on other machines.
I dont even know if it s working but...

... now I plan to clone and LUSK-encrypt my clones.
Im said LUSK is very simplier to "make" at install.
But I dont plan to install, I plan to clone.

Is there any hope to make such clone automatically (factory thinking) ?

Answer (score 0):

Summary (I think):

You want to set up a raspberry pie and then clone that setup to other computers.

That's what I'm guessing.

I would make an entire copy of the hard drive and then copy that.

I googled and found:

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-super-easy-r-1261113524

http://lifehacker.com/easily-backup-and-clone-raspberry-pi-sd-cards-1620293961

http://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-cards-with-windows--mac-59294

http://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-clone-raspberry-pi-sd-cards-using-the-command-line-in-os-x--mac-59911

Comment: merci Michael. Mais au delà du clone, je cherche a crypter le disk (Lusk). --- Beyond cloning, I aim to Lusk-encrypt. It is generally - and easyly - done at install, trying to Lusk-encrypt a ready installed system is an expert hassle. I wonder how I could clone and crypt in the same time...